# Can we have SDK inside another SDK in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, sdk

Let's suppose there is a SDK 'A' that i will be invoking from the app. Now, there is one SDK 'B' and my SDK 'A' is highly dependent on SDK 'B' so what i want to do is invoke the SDK 'B' from SDK 'A' and SDK 'A' from the app.

I tried doing this, and i was even able to use the methods of SDK 'B' inside the SDK 'A' but i am not able to generate `aar` file of my SDK 'A' after this.

Comment: Simply replace "SDK" by "library" and what you describe is the library dependency system.

Comment: We dont have the library for that, have SDK only. Thats why asked this question.